# Transaction mediator in wso2esb 4.8.0

Tags: postgresql, transactions, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm working with wso2esb 4.8.0 and i go through this scenario which is given in wso2esb documentation.I want to copy the records from first database to second database as soon as i delete them from first database.but when i put the duplicate record it should neither delete from first nor insert into second.

my proxy service :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Transaction_mediator"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="name"
                   expression="//name/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="id"
                   expression="//id/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="price"
                   expression="//price/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <transaction action="new"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="text" value="Reporting to the DB1"/>
         </log>
         <dbreport useTransaction="true">
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <dsName>DS1</dsName>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>
            delete from c1 where name=?</sql>
               <parameter expression="get-property('name')" type="VARCHAR"/>
            </statement>
         </dbreport>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="text" value="Reporting to the DB2"/>
         </log>
         <dbreport useTransaction="true">
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <dsName>DS2</dsName>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>
               INSERT into c1 values (?,?,?)</sql>
               <parameter expression="get-property('name')" type="VARCHAR"/>
               <parameter expression="get-property('id')" type="INTEGER"/>
               <parameter expression="get-property('price')" type="INTEGER"/>
            </statement>
         </dbreport>
         <transaction action="commit"/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

It's working but error occurred when i put **duplicate records**.At that time It **deleting** records from first but not inserting into second database.What should i do?is their any solution?let me know.

Comment: will you able to paste carbon log here?

Comment: Actually It working but if i put duplicate record then it get delete from first table but not inserting in second table and showing error like : DBReportMediator Error execuring insert statement : INSERT into c1 values (?,?,?) against DataSource : DS2
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "c1_pkey"
  Detail: Key (name)=(SUN) already exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with transaction mediator with JDBC and it has been reported in the [wso2 esb issue tracker](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3581). Therefore, this may be fixed in feature releases.